# Assembly fast division by 2

Tags: assembly, division

Is there a faster way of dividing by 2, with sign, in assembly than the one in the example below?

```
...
mov ecx, 2
idiv ecx
push eax #push the result
...
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sure:

```
sar eax, 1
```

The `sar` opcode differs from `shr` in that the most significant (sign) bit is preserved in `sar`, and it is set to 0 in `shr`. The [Arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) page on Wikipedia shows much more detail about this operation in a general context.

Note that on a 2's complement machine (which the x86 is) this actually calculates `floor(eax / 2)`. In particular, that means that for an integer *x*:

- for *x = 0*, the result is 0
- for *x > 0*, the result is *floor(x / 2)*
- for *x < 0*, the result is also *floor(x / 2)*, or *-ceil(-x / 2)*

The latter result gives results that may be unexpected. For example, -3 sar 1 results in -2, not -1. On the other hand, 3 sar 1 results in 1.

Comment: exactly. as Greg points out, a shift to the right by 1 is the same as a divide by 2 :-)